# AutoMapper - Map for Parent class and ICollection child class

Tags: c#, automapper

I have two classes and I want to map between two parent objects including the list of children. But I cannot add `Include` property in AutoMapper.

```cs
public class ParentRequestDto
{
    public ParentRequestDto()
    {
       Children = new List<ChildDto>();
    }
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
        
    public ICollection<ChildDto> Children  { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public class ChildDto
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

I also have the basic model of these dtos

```cs
public class Parent
{
    public Parent()
    {
       Children = new List<Child>();
    }
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
        
    public ICollection<Child> Children  { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public class Child
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

My mapping class is like this:

```cs
CreateMap<ParentRequestDto, Parent>()
    .Include<ChildDto, Child>()
```

My question is how to convert each other in AutoMapper. Currently, I can't do it like this. All child objects return null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `.Include<Source, Destination>()` only when specifying the mapping to inherit type from the base type as stated in the [documentation](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Mapping-inheritance.html), which currently I don't see any of your code implements the inheritance.

Instead, you should create another mapping rule for mapping the `ChildDto` to the `Child` type.

```cs
CreateMap<ParentRequestDto, Parent>();

CreateMap<ChildDto, Child>();
```

Comment: I have child mapping rule in another classs. Should they be in the same class?

Comment: Both mapping rules can work without the need to be in the same class.  As you can define the configuration to register profile with assembly. By defining the assembly as this [Dependency Injection](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Dependency-injection.html) documentation, AutoMapper will scan the whole library/namespace to find the class which implements the Profile class and register it.

By right, if your child mapping profile is registered, you won't get any exception that missing the mapping rule. Do you get any exception regarding missing profile for mapping `ChildDto` to `Child`?

Comment: I register automapper like this
            services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup).Assembly);
I should check why does not work in another class.
By the way your suggestion works well for me. Thanks a lot